# How to make regex seeks another match?

Tags: regex

I have a string

```
one two three four five six seven
```

I want a regex to match any two words near each other, so I use the the following regex

```
\w+ \w+
```

Which match

```
one two
three four 
five six
```

What regex should I use to get the following match? :

```
two three
four five
six seven
```

Comment: Why `one two` in incorrect?

Comment: You would have to write your own custom implementation of regex searching in your language of choice (i.e. find the first match "one two" and then re-evaluate the expression starting with the character after the position of the first match). This is because regex greedily matches as much as it can from left to right..inherently, it can't have overlapping matches.

Comment: @Sam: It can't have overlapping matches as the main match, but it is always possible in capturing group.

Comment: True @nhahtdh, OP see this expression: [`(\w+)(?= (\w+))`](https://regex101.com/r/xW1tC1/2)

Comment: Seems that the word at the start of the string should just be ignored. `(?<!\A)\b\w+ \w+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a negative lookbehind, if your regex engine supports it.

```
(?<= )\w+ \w+
```

For example, in Ruby:

```
irb(main):001:0> 'one two three four five six seven'.scan /(?<= )\w+ \w+/
=> ["two three", "four five", "six seven"]
```